# Python Pillow and Tkinter resizing image by resizing the window

Tags: python, tkinter, resize, python-imaging-library

I am trying to learn Pillow and Tkinter.
I am facing a problem here.
I want to open an image but when I open it without declaring the geometry of the tkinter window then the image opens to the original size.
When I declare the geometry then the image is cropped to the window size (not resized). When I try to resize the image then again the image is cropped.
Is there any way I can open an image and fit it to a window, resize the image as window is resized,  work on this displayed image and when saving it after whatever changes I have done, then the image is saved to its original size?

The basic code I am using is this:

```
from PIL import Image, ImagkeTK
import tkinter as tk 


mw = tk.Tk()
mw.geometry("800x600")

img = Image.open("test1.jpg")
imgresize=img.resize((600,600), Image.ANTIALIAS)
tkimage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(imgresize)
tk.Label(mw, image=tkimage).pack()
imgresize.save("imgresize.png")

mw.mainloop()
```

Thank you. :)

Comment: **but when I open it without declaring the geometry of the tkinter window then the image opens to the original size**.But you have used `.resize()`.It must show the resized image.

Comment: You can bind `<Configure>` event to the root window and resize the image in the event callback.

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA I mean when I dont use this parameter in the code.

Comment: @acw1668 please can you give me an example?

Comment: [here](https://pastebin.com/GJUEut8e) is an example.

Comment: @acw1668 Thank you! you are very helpful. I now have to figure out what this code does actually because it seems to be working as I need.

Comment: @acw1668 I am trying to understand the whole code you wrote. 
So first you create a function that takes as argument an event and you will bind it with the <Configure> event that is used for resizing the window.
In the funciton I cannot understand the two last lines .config and .image. 
Why we using .config there for the attributes and what does .image does (havent found info on this)?
Also I cannot understand (in the main tkinter code to create the window) why Label is used and not Frame. How can a frame be used?
I also want to thank you for another time for your time spent to write this.

Comment: The `imgbox.config(image=tkimage)` is to change the image of `imgbox` to new one.  The `imgbox.image = tkimage` is to save a reference of the new image otherwise the new image will be garbage collected since it is created as a local variable inside a function.  Why using Label in main code?  Because your posted code uses Label.